# FAILED test_main.py::test_login_success - assert 405 == 200

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fastapi

I am new to pytest and working on to test the code. How ever the test result showing failed.

```
**main.py**

@app.post("/loginsuccess/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def login_success(request: Request, username: str = Form(...), password: str = Form(...)):
    p = await User_Pydantic.from_tortoise_orm(await User.get(username=username, password=password))
    json_compatible_item_data = jsonable_encoder(p)
    if json_compatible_item_data is not None:
        logger.info("Logged in Successfully")
        return templates.TemplateResponse("homepage.html", {"request": request, "username":username})
    else:
        status_code:int
        status_code = 500
        logger.error("Invalid Credentials")
        return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request":request, "status_code":status_code})
```

```
**test_main.py**

def test_login_success():
    response = client.get('/loginsuccess/', json={'username': 'sheik', 'password':'abdullah'})
    assert response.status_code==200
```

The test result below

```
================================================================== short test summary info ==================================================================
FAILED test_main.py::test_login_success - assert 405 == 200
```

Comment: 405 means wrong HTTP method. Your endpoint is defined to use POST (`@app.post`) but your test is using GET (`client.get`). So it is expected for the test to fail.

Comment: Hi Gino, Thanks for your reply.  I have modified it and now i am getting this error

Comment: FAILED test_main.py::test_login_success - assert 422 == 200

Comment: Check your endpoint. Check what is the correct URL. Check the expected query parameters or body payload or form data. Then call it properly in your test.

Comment: The end point is correct but i am stuck on how to pass username and password values to the test inorder to check it

Answer (score 0):

actually, the response you are getting from the server is 405, not 200. That is why your assertion is failing.

HTTP 405 is Method Not Allowed response status code indicates that the request method is known by the server but is not supported by the target resource.

Just make sure that the server/backend handles `/loginsuccess/` as a **Post** request
It looks that your request has invalid arguments or the backend is not configured the right way.

Comment: I have modified it now i am getting this error FAILED test_main.py::test_login_success - assert 422 == 200

Comment: Could you please guide me how to fix it

Comment: have you used client.post now?

Comment: yes i have used it...after using it i am getting this error FAILED test_main.py::test_login_success - assert 422 == 200

Comment: you also need to pass data in the form of json object, 
import J=json
foo = {'username': 'sheik', 'password':'abdullah'}
json_data = json.dumps(foo)

then pass this data to client.post()

Comment: I did like this def test_login_success():
    import json
    foo = {'username': 'sheik', 'password':'abdullah'}
    json_data = json.dumps(foo)
    response = client.post('/loginsuccess/', json_data)
    assert response.status_code==200

Comment: but same error FAILED test_main.py::test_login_success - assert 422 == 200

Comment: `411` means you're missing required data. However, you should update your actual question and not leave details in the comments. In this case the original question was resolved, so you should make a new question with the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to pass data in the form of json object,

```
import json
foo = {'username': 'sheik', 'password':'abdullah'}
json_data = json.dumps(foo)
```

then pass this data to client.post()